Need Clarification on a problem about finding Laurent series
I am working on the following problem:

Let $f(z) = \frac{1}{(1+z^2)(2-z)^2}$. Determine the principal part of $f$ at $z=2$ and determine the region where the Laurent series of $f$ at $z=2$ converges.

Since $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{i, -i, 2\}$, there are two Laurent expansions of $f$ around $z=2$, one that converges in $B(2, \sqrt{5})$, and the other that converges in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \bar{B}(2, \sqrt{5})$. By partial fraction, I find $$f(z) = \frac{4z+3}{25(z^2+1)} - \frac{4}{25(z-2)} + \frac{1}{5(z-2)^2}.$$
Since the first term above is analytic everywhere except at $z=i, -i,$ does this mean $-\frac{4}{25(z-2)} + \frac{1}{5(z-2)^2}$ is the principal part of both of the two Laurent series around $z=2$?
I am confused about what it means to say "the principal part of $f$ at $z=2$" or "the Laurent series of $f$ at $z=2$" because Laurent series around $2$ isn't unique. I do not know how to answer the question "determine the region where the Laurent series of $f$ at $z=2$ converges". Region of which Laurent series? When people say "the" Laurent series, do people typically mean one or the other?

The Laurent series at $z=2$ is the unique expansion of $f(z)$ in powers of $z-2$ that converges on $B(2,r)\setminus{2}$ for some $r>0$, and its principal part is the portion of it consisting of powers with negative exponents. You found it, and you also found $r$.

@AnneBauval I see. I did not know there was as difference between Laurent series at $z=2$ and around $z=2$, but now that makes sense. Thank you.
